# Is Kotlin Flow's Collect is only internal kotlinx.coroutines API?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Taking the direct example from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#flows-are-cold

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling simple function...")
    val flow = simple()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value -> println(value) } 
    println("Calling collect again...")
    flow.collect { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

I got the error on `collect`.

```
This is an internal kotlinx.coroutines API that should not be used from outside of kotlinx.coroutines. No compatibility guarantees are provided.It is recommended to report your use-case of internal API to kotlinx.coroutines issue tracker, so stable API could be provided instead
```

When I add `@InternalCoroutinesApi`

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling simple function...")
    val flow = simple()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value -> println(value) }
    println("Calling collect again...")
    flow.collect { value -> println(value) }
}
```

I get an error in the `collect`'s lambda (function of `value -> println(value`) as below

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
FlowCollector<Int>
Found:
([ERROR :  ]) → Unit
Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
```

I am using Kotlin version 1.4.21.

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.2"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2'
```

Did I do anything wrong that I cannot compile the example code in Android Studio?

Comment: add `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, the title is making sense, as apparently Kotlin `collect` is not internal kotlinx.collection.API only. It's the error message that mislead one into thinking it is and go down the wrong solution.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. Thanks for clarifying. I wonder why this "This is an internal kotlinx.coroutines API that should not be used from outside of kotlinx.coroutines." was generated then. Was there another 'collect' function that was already available (but not fit), or was this error coming from a totally different thing?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The answer is, NO, `collect` is not only internal kotlinx.coroutines API. The error message is misleading.

As per @ir42's comment, `add import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect`  solve the problem.

**Additional info, why I didn't pick `collectLatest` as the answer**

`collect` and `collectLatest` is different.

Using this example

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { // flow builder
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) // pretend we are doing something useful here
        emit(i) // emit next value
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    // Launch a concurrent coroutine to check if the main thread is blocked
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }
    // Collect the flow
    simple().collect { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

Collect will produce

```
I'm not blocked 1
1
I'm not blocked 2
2
I'm not blocked 3
3
```

as per https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html

But `collectLatest`

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { // flow builder
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) // pretend we are doing something useful here
        emit(i) // emit next value
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    // Launch a concurrent coroutine to check if the main thread is blocked
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }
    // Collect the flow
    simple().collectLatest { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

will produce

```
I'm not blocked 1
I'm not blocked 2
1
I'm not blocked 3
2
```

Comment: import is not working on kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0-RC2

Comment: @di0n0s This seems to be an issue specific to 1.6.0-RC2. 
See this issue report: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3078
It has been fixed https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/3082 so I think it will arrive on the next release.

-> Use `1.6.0-RC`, skip `1.6.0-RC2` and wait for the next release.

Comment: @di0n0s version `1.6.0-RC3` has been released and the issue existing in `1.6.0-RC3` has been resolved. It is mentioned in the release notes: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.6.0-RC3

Comment: This is still an issue if you use `Flow.flowWithLifecycle.collect()`. I had to switch to using `repeatOnLifecycle` instead.

Comment: how come this misleading error message shows up? @@

Answer (score 20):

Add below import:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
```

Comment: IDEA constantly removing this import as not used/ optimized. without it, I have this compilation error

Comment: @VictorMikhailov try to disable import optimization : `File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Optimize imports on the fly`

Answer (score 8):

I finally found the solution for it after it almost drove me mad.
As none of the solutions here worked for me, I had a special case where I was working on a multi-modules project and collect() kept throwing out this error everywhere and even manually importing it didn't fix it.

What solved the issue for me is explicitly adding coroutines dependency to ALL of my project's modules build.gradle files, not just the app's one, even those modules that don't use coroutines.

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2")
```

Answer (score 6):

For version `1.6.0-RC3` and newer:

The `@InternalCoroutinesApi` annotations have been removed from all `collect()` functions (see [this PR](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/3082)).

That means we won't see the error anymore and also won't need the import

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
```

anymore because (together with the changes of [another PR](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/3047)) we can now use the `collect()` member function directly.

Comment: All the `kotlin 1.6.x` not working,  but `1.5.2`  everything is ok

Answer (score 4):

The Api changed in newer versions of kotlinx coroutines and instead of a lambda in the collect function, it should go as the final call in the chain. The documentation example:

```
flow
  .onEach { value -> process(value) }
  .catch { e -> handleException(e) }
  .collect() // trigger collection of the flow
```

Comment: According to the above mentioned doc 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html 
the collect {} syntax should still work, it says "It is a shorthand for collect {}."
.. which it doesn't.

The current answer, anyway, should be the accepted answer at the current date.

Answer (score 1):

Just casting as the same object (here, `StateFlow`) worked for me, like below:

```
(flow as StateFlow).collect { value -> println(value) }
```

Answer (score -6):

Replace `collect` with `collectLatest`.

Comment: collect and collectLatest is different